# Not able to render Folder page content of template in TYPO3

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I have created one default column for the footer section for my template. And by using this typoscript.

```
lib.footer = COA
lib.footer {
10 = CONTENT
10 {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=4
}
}
```

And tried this one too,

```
lib.footer = CONTENT
lib.footer {
table = tt_content
select.orderBy = sorting
select.where = colPos=4
slide = -1
}
```

I am able to render in the all pages except the pages which are in the Folder. So, what should be the solution in this case ?

[Backendview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAxhO.png)

[Outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDYnZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this for display content.

```
lib.footer = RECORDS
lib.footer {
    source = 1     // add content id
    dontCheckPid = 1
    tables = tt_content
}
```

For footer Menu like `AGB |TEST |` use below typoscript

```
lib.footermenu = COA
lib.footermenu{
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>

    20 = HMENU
    20 {
        special = directory
        # special.value will contain the page ID of the Footer menu page
        special.value = 20  
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            target = _self
            NO {
                allWrap = <li>|</li>
            }
        }
    }
}
```